# Does die have to be used if opening a file fails?

Tags: perl

Most of time, I do something like this:

```
open FH, ">file.txt" or die "Cann't open file: $!";
```

Does `die` have to be used? If I want my script to continue (and simply ignore the error if the file cannot be opened), what should I do?

Comment: Please never use Barewords `FH` or the 2 Argument way of open. ALWAYS use `open my $fh, '>','file.txt'`. Its safer because Barewords are global. Also with the way of opening (reading, appending, writing, .. ). When you use a Variable for the Filename, it could start with something unreliable, dubious (like a Pipe...) =)

Comment: Please never make blanket statements like that. What he’s doing it perfectly fine in many situations.

Comment: @tchrist: However, lexical file handles together with the three-argument form of `open` is "perfectly fine" in more situations and has no disadvantages. It is common sense to adopt it as a standard practice, and you do Perl a disservice by criticising an attempt to evangelise it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You might want to do something like

```
if(open my $fh, ">", "file.txt") {
    # do stuff with file
    close $fh;
}
else {
    # do stuff without file
}
```

Comment: In else, Is it good for me to use goto ( such as goto Exit; and at the end of the script, Exit: exit(-1);)?

Comment: @ericyoung - No. No, it is not. You'll be much better off if you pretend that Perl has no implementation of `goto`. And you can always do `open(my $fh,">","file.txt") or exit(-1);`

Comment: @JackManey: Actually, that's not strictly true. The `goto &SUB` version of `goto` is really useful :-)

Comment: @ericyoung Wait.  So your question is about how to avoid throwing an exception so you can reimplement exceptions?  Are you really asking how to make it so that `die` does not abort the program?

Comment: @darch Not exactly. I simply do not want script to die because we need to call our ExitStatus function at the end of the script, which is required by our execution engine. This function does things such as logging, adding data to database. If scipt dies, then this function won't be called.

Comment: @ericyoung That's a restatement of what I was saying, and the correct answer is "Catch the exception.".

Answer (score 8):

The code doesn't have to `die` if it cannot access the file.

If writing to the file is optional, you might do something like this:

```
my $file_is_ok = 0;
open FH, ">file.txt" and $file_is_ok = 1;
warn "No logging available" unless $file_is_ok;
```

Then wherever you want to use the file handle, you can check first that it is ok:

```
$file_is_ok and print FH "Something happened";
```

Usually you'll want a little more abstraction than the above, but I hope that is enough to get started.

Answer (score 5):

No, `die` most definitely doesn't have to be used, or else a failed `open` would simply exit the program.  This is just a commonly used construct since often if you can't open a file there's no point in continuing, but there really is no requirement to `die` or to do anything else either.

Answer (score 1):

I might do something like:

```
sub process_file {
    my $file = shift;
    open(my $fh, ">", $file) or return;
    # write to file ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
open(my $fh, ">", $file) or print "open failed , you are on your own\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use `croak()` from `Carp` instead, especially in modules or objects. See http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html

`Carp` is a standard module and, like all standard modules, comes installed with Perl. A list of all the standard modulesis available in `perlmodlib`. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for responding to a few months old question, but the way I do this is by implementing my own `die` style subroutine:

```
sub fail {
    my $text = $_[0];

    # Do error-related stuff here, like send an email
    die($text) # or just exit
}

open(my $fh, ">file.txt") or fail("Unable to open file: $!");
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a try catch block, using Try::Tiny or something of the sort.

Comment: while i did not -1, IMO this is a comment, not an answer.. and it sounds a bit pythonic, not perlis...

Comment: i did not -1 either, but the OP wants to ignore errors, and open() does not die by default, so this is not even an answer, unless the OP is using autodie, which would be dumb if he wants to ignore errors.

Comment: @deathapril You're right that it's not perlish assuming this is 1998.

Answer (score -1):

If what you are trying to do is avoid exiting the program when you encounter an error opening a file, omitting the `die` is not the correct approach.  `die` is Perl's exception mechanism; the fact that it aborts the program by default is an accidental, not fundamental, property.  If you supply an exception handler, you retain control.  The correct approach is to catch the exception and do your cleanup in the `finally` block.

```
use 5.10.0;
use Try::Tiny;

my ($infile, $FH);
try {
    open $infile, '<', 'infile.txt' or die "Can't open infile";
    try { 
        open $FH, '>', 'file.txt'   or die "Can't open outfile";
        my $line = <$infile>;
        print $FH $line;
        say 'Cleaning up $FH';
        close $FH;
    } finally {
        say 'Cleaning up $infile';
        close $infile;
    } catch {
        die $_;
    };
} catch {
    die $_;
};
```

So if `open $infile ...` fails, `die` to the `catch` block, which redies and aborts the script.  But once we've opened `$infile`, if `open $FH` fails, die to a catch block that also aborts the program but forces `close $infile` to happen first.  File handles aren't the best examples of resources to clean up before program exit because the interpreter closes files automatically, but the basic idea is there.

If you don't like the nested `try` blocks, you can achieve a very similar effect by checking which exception caused the block to abort and deciding what cleanup is necessary based on that.  That's a little more fragile, but still more robust than anything mentioning `goto`.