# readdir() attempted on invalid dirhandle $par_dir

Tags: perl

I am trying just to execute a perl script inside multiple folders, but I don't understand why I have a problem with readdir() attempted on invalid dirhandle $par_dir. $parent is printed good but $par_dir is printed like "GLOB(0x17e7a68)".

Any idea of why it is happening? Thanks a lot!

Here the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use Cwd;
use FileHandle;
use File::Glob;

my $parent = "/media/sequentia/NAS/projects/131-prgdb3/01-   DATA/All_plant_genomes_proteomes";

my ($par_dir, $sub_dir);

opendir($par_dir, $parent);

print $parent."\n";

print $par_dir."\n";

while (my $sub_folders = readdir($par_dir)) {

next if ($sub_folders =~ /^..?$/);  # skip . and ..
my $path = $parent . '/' . $sub_folders;

next unless (-d $path);   # skip anything that isn't a directory

print $path."\n";

chdir($path) or die;

 @files = glob( $path. '/*' );

    foreach $filename (@files){

        print $filename ."\n";

        system ("grep 'comment' PutativeGenes.txt | wc -l");
        system ("grep 'class' PutativeGenes.txt | wc -l");

    }

}
closedir($par_dir);
```

Comment: Probably `opendir()` is failing giving the invalid file handle. Try to check for errors: `opendir($par_dir, $parent) or die "opendir() failed: $!";`

Comment: You *must always* `use strict` at the top of every Perl program you write

Comment: @SilentMonk: It's a ***handle*** to the directory. A handler is something completely different

Comment: @Borodin, Thanks. I will delete the comment so that others don't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that the directory you specify in `$parent` doesn't exist. You must always check to make sure that a call to `open` or `opendir` succeeded before going on to use the handle

That path step `01-   DATA` is suspicious. I would expect `01-DATA` or perhaps `01- DATA` with a single space, but multiple spaces are rarely used because they are invisible and difficult to count

Here are some other thoughts on your program

- You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write. That will alert you to many simple errors that you may otherwise overlook
- Your statement `next if ( $sub_folders =~ /^..?$/ )` is wrong because the dots must be escaped. As it is you are discarding any name that is one or two characters in length
- If your path really does contain spaces then you need to `use File::Glob ':bsd_glob'`, as otherwise the spaces will be treated as separators between multipl glob patterns
- You execute the `foreach` loop for every file or directory found in `$path`, but your `system` calls aren't affected by the name of that file, so you're making the same call multiple times

It's worth noting that `glob` will do all the directory searching for you. I would write something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';

my $parent_dir = "/media/sequentia/NAS/projects/131-prgdb3/01-DATA/All_plant_genomes_proteomes";

print "$parent_dir\n";

while ( my $path = glob "$parent_dir/*" ) {

    next unless -d $path;

    print "$path\n";

    chdir $path or die qq{Unable to chdir to "$path": $!};

    while ( my $filename = glob "$path/*" ) {

        next unless -f $filename;

        print "$filename\n";

        system "grep 'comment' PutativeGenes.txt | wc -l";
        system "grep 'class'   PutativeGenes.txt | wc -l";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `opendir()` is failing giving the invalid file handle (probably it fails because you try to open a nonexistent `$parent` directory).

If [`opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) fails it will return false, and `$par_dir` is left unchanged as `undef`. If you attempt to call `readdir()` on an undefined file handle you will get a runtime warning like:

```
readdir() attempted on invalid dirhandle at ...
```

Therefore you should always check the return code from `opendir`. For example, you can do:

```
opendir($par_dir, $parent) or die "opendir() failed: $!";
```

or see more suggestions on what to do in this link  [Does die have to be used if opening a file fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306466/does-die-have-to-be-used-if-opening-a-file-fails)

Note that your code could have been simplified using [`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule), for example:

```
my @dirs = File::Find::Rule
   ->directory->maxdepth(1)->mindepth(1)->in( $parent );

for my $dir (@dirs) {
    say "$dir";
    my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->maxdepth(1)->in( $dir );
    say "--> $_" for @files;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't need the directory names:

```
my @files = File::Find::Rule
    ->file->maxdepth(2)->mindepth(2)->in( $parent );
say for @files;
```